# What are exactly three distinct proper ideals in $ \frac {Q(X)}{X^3}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

What are exactly three distinct proper ideals in $ \frac {Q(X)}{X^3}$?

Can anyone give me a hint for proceeding.

Comment: $(0), (X), (X^2)$.

Comment: What is $Q(X)$?

Comment: $(x + <x^3>)$ @Arthur...Then how could I find the other two ? How could I conclude they would exhaust the whole set of Proper Ideals?

Comment: $Q(X)$ is an Euclidean Domain.@Arthur

Comment: Which one will give the ideal $(X+1)$? $ (X+1)$ is certainly an ideal .SO EITHER it will merge with any of your ideal or it will be whole $A $@pompelle

Comment: $(X+1)$ is a unit, and it generates the entire ring.

Comment: If $\mathbb Q=Q$ then $Q[x]$ is a principal ideal domain and the ideals of this ring correspond to the ideals of $Q[x]$ that contain $x^3$. You will be able to find this and explanations thereof on this site, and in most basic algebra books.

Comment: how $x + 1$ is unit I did not get...@rschwieb

Comment: @cmi Do you know what a unit is?'

Comment: when it will have an multiplicative inverse...@rschwieb

Comment: $(X+1)(X−1)=1$ How?

Comment: @cmi Sorry: just noticed I had given the inverse in a different quotient ring $Q[x]/(X^2)$. What I meant to write was $(X+1)(X^2-X+1)=1$

Comment: I did not get u. I have not yet understood the procedure to find the three distinct Ideals. @rschwieb

Comment: I did not get you. Can you please elaborate little bit more ?@rschwieb

Comment: I got it ...@rschwieb

Comment: U are right. I got U..@pompelle